# Python Twisted: how do use different resource hierarchies for localhost connections?

Tags: python, resources, twisted

I'd like to use one resource hierarchy for localhost connections and another resource hierarchy for all other connections. How would I go about this?

```
publicSite = Site(File("/var/www/"))
localhostSite = Site(File("/var/localhost/"))

publicServer = TCPServer(80, publicSite, interface="0.0.0.0")
localhostServer = TCPServer(80, localhostSite, interface="127.0.0.1")
```

It seems that you can't listen to two different interfaces at the same time.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/twistd", line 21, in <module>
  run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 27, in run
  app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 379, in run
  runApp(config)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
  _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 158, in run
  self.postApplication()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 213, in postApplication
  startApplication(self.config, self.application)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 174, in startApplication
  service.IService(application).privilegedStartService()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 228, in privilegedStartService
  service.privilegedStartService()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/application/internet.py", line 68, in privilegedStartService
  self._port = self._getPort()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/application/internet.py", line 86, in _getPort
  return getattr(reactor, 'listen'+self.method)(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 467, in listenTCP
  p.startListening()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 733, in startListening
  raise CannotListenError, (self.interface, self.port, le)
twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 127.0.0.1:80: (98, 'Address already in use').
```

1

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question.  What's wrong with the answer you provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of binding to `0.0.0.0` for the second server, bind to one or more public addresses on your server.  Twisted doesn't provide any APIs for enumerating the addresses on a host, nor for differentiating between public and private addresses (because perhaps your "public" address is a 10.x.x.x and a firewall is forwarding traffic from an '''actually''' public address).

If you need to discover your addresses instead of letting them be supplied by configuration, then on POSIX, [this ioctl example might help](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439093-get-names-of-all-up-network-interfaces-linux-only/).

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks. In my particular situation though, I decided to create a custom resource that checks to the client ip address using request.getClientIP() and chooses a different ip address if the ip address is 127.0.0.01